# Enable VeeValidate on Form

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vee-validate

Currently I'm trying to add VeeValidate component to validate my form on Laravel, I just have installed Vue with NPM and it seems to be working, but how to enable a component for Vue?

Currently I have in my app.js:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.JQuery = require('jquery');
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.component('ValidationProvider', require('vee-validate'));
```

and attempt to call component in view:

```
        const app = new Vue({
            el:'#app',
            components: {
                ValidationProvider
            },
            data() {
                return {
                    step:1,
                    registration:{
                        firstname:null,
                        lastname:null,
                        email:null,
                        street:null,
                        city:null,
                        state:null,
                    }
                }
            },
            methods:{
                prev() {
                    this.step--;
                },
                next() {
                    this.step++;
                },


            }
        });
```

Console says Validationprovider is not defined... Why?

Comment: Have you tried following the VeeValidate docs for importing and registering the components?
https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/basics.html#registering-the-validation-provider

Comment: Yeah, I've tried to call it globally - no luck so far

Answer (score 0):

The `ValidationProvider` is just one component out of many exported by vee-validate, you need to import it specifically.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';

Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider);
```